# Calculating true rate of a loan with an origination fee

Tags: loans, interest-rate

If I have a loan of 1000 at a rate of 5% for 3 years compounded monthly, but I pay a 100 origination fee, do I calculate the loan on the original loan amount, or the reduced amount (1000-100)?

Comment: by "calculate the loan" do you mean find the regular payment, or the interest rate?

Answer (score 1):

If I put the numbers you give and include the 36 monthly payments of `=PMT(0.05/12,36,1000)` into the `XIRR` function of Excel, then I get a "true" interest rate of 12.88%.

That up-front fee really whacks your interest rate!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd use $900 as the amount borrowed, along with required payments and calculate the rate from there.